# Instanciar objeto em swift e preencher com dados de um webapi

Tags: ios, swift

Já pesquisei em vários sites e vídeos do YouTube e não encontro nada sobre isso, se houver alguém com disposição para me demonstrar esse código agradeço, porque não me basta olhar a documentação da Apple, gostaria de uma explicação de alguém que entenda do assunto e até me dizer se é uma boa pratica desenvolver algo nessa linha de raciocínio

Tenho um webapi que retorna uma lista de provas em JSON:

```
{
 "Provas": [
{
  "Codigo": "16505984073",
  "Disciplina": {
    "Codigo": "657060",
   "Nome": "DISCIPLINA 1"
  },
  "Tipo": "SUB",
  "Correcao": "2016-07-01T14:33:33.383",
 },
{
  "Codigo": "16994242303",
  "Disciplina": {
    "Codigo": "652640",
    "Nome": "DISCIPLINA 2"
  },
  "Tipo": "SUB",
  "Correcao": "2016-06-30T11:53:11.207",
 },
{
  "Codigo": "16916014662",
  "Disciplina": {
    "Codigo": "652540",
    "Nome": "DISCIPLINA 3"
  },
  "Tipo": "BIMESTRAL",
  "Correcao": "2016-06-29T09:42:29.097",
 },
{
  "Codigo": "16892010587",
  "Disciplina": {
    "Codigo": "656140",
   "Nome": "DISCIPLINA 4"
  },
  "Tipo": "BIMESTRAL",
  "Correcao": "2016-06-25T14:49:57.17",
 },
{
  "Codigo": "16435696693",
  "Disciplina": {
    "Codigo": "611460",
    "Nome": "DISCIPLINA 5"
  },
  "Tipo": "BIMESTRAL",
  "Correcao": "2016-05-04T15:42:08.363",
 },
{
  "Codigo": "16781197682",
  "Disciplina": {
    "Codigo": "567140",
    "Nome": "DISCIPLINA 6"
  },
  "Tipo": "SUB",
  "Correcao": "2016-05-04T15:38:09.707",
 },
{
  "Codigo": "16496847758",
  "Disciplina": {
    "Codigo": "554740",
    "Nome": "DISCIPLINA 7"
  },
  "Tipo": "SUB",
  "Correcao": "2016-05-03T15:45:38.553",
 },
{
  "Codigo": "16640802740",
  "Disciplina": {
    "Codigo": "538740",
    "Nome": "DISCIPLINA 8"
  },
  "Tipo": "SUB",
  "Correcao": "2016-05-03T14:50:06.06",
 }
  ]
}
```

E tenho uma classe Prova

```
import Foundation

class Prova
{
    let codigo:String
    let tipo:String
    let dtcorrecao:NSDate
    let disciplina:Disciplina

    init(codigo:String, tipo:String, dtcorrecao:NSDate, disciplina:Disciplina)
    {
        self.codigo = codigo
        self.tipo = tipo
        self.dtcorrecao = dtcorrecao
        self.disciplina = disciplina
    }
}
```

e outra chama Disciplina

```
import Foundation

class Disciplina
{
    let codigo:String
    let nomedisciplina:String

    init(codigo:String, nomedisciplina:String)
    {
        self.codigo = codigo
        self.nomedisciplina = nomedisciplina
    }
}
```

Gostaria de preencher este retorno do wepapi instanciando meu objeto "Prova" e depois popular uma tabela até consegui fazer isso recebendo os dados do ''JSON'' usando o ''Alamofire'' e populando meu objeto com esses dados usando o ''ObjectMapper'', porém gostaria de saber se há algo nativo do ''Swift 3.0'' pois agora com a atualização da linguagem ''Alamofire'' e ''ObjectMapper'' estão dando muitos erros e tambem não acho trivial depender de soluções de terceiros. Também não sei se essa seria a boa pratica para trabalhar com dados web(Retornar dados em ''JSON'' e converter em Objeto), caso não seja poderiam me mostrar qual seria em codigo para ''Swift 3.0'', estou com o ''Xcode 8'' já.

Answer (score 1):

Uma API boa pra fazer isso é a EVReflection.

https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection

O branch master dela é para Swift 3.0 já e fica extremamente fácil de fazer a conversão, é só colocar no cabeçalho da classe que ela é um EVObject e depois usar a construtora.

```
class Prova : EVObject
{
    let codigo:String
    let tipo:String
    let dtcorrecao:NSDate
    let disciplina:Disciplina

    init(codigo:String, tipo:String, dtcorrecao:NSDate, disciplina:Disciplina)
    {
        self.codigo = codigo
        self.tipo = tipo
        self.dtcorrecao = dtcorrecao
        self.disciplina = disciplina
    }
}
```

Aí você só usa a construtora:

```
let jsonString = respostaDoSeuWebServer()
let provaObj = Prova(json: jsonString)
```

Se tiver mais dúvidas, aqui tem um tutorial bom, em menos de 5 minutos ensina a fazer tanto a GET request quanto a conversão:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPWsQD2nxqg